# ZF2 how to pass URL segments as Action params

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

I got URLS like:

> http://www.example.com/r/4442323222344/HLKKLKLKLKLKLKH

I'd like to map the two segments  (4442323222344 and HLKKLKLKLKLKLKH) of the URL as params of my **redirectAction** function, so *$messageId* is "**4442323222344**" and *$hash* is "**HLKKLKLKLKLKLKH**"

This's the route:

```
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
             ....
            'redirect' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/r',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'redirect',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/:messageId/:hash',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'messageId' => '[a-zA-Z0-9]+',
                                'hash'     => '[a-zA-Z0-9]+',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            ...
        ),
   ),
```

And that's the action:

```
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController implements ConfigAwareInterface
{
    ...
    public function redirectAction($messageId,$hash)
    {
      ...
      myFunc($messageId,$hash);
      ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I'm aware that I can have these segment using:

```
$_messageId = $this->params()->fromRoute('messageId');
$_hash = $this->params()->fromRoute('hash');
```

but I found pass variabiles via function params is more "clean".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible to be done like this. It is an idea as an improvement for ZF3 (which will be released not anytime soon, so no worries), but in ZF2 you won't see this feature released.

You will need to go with using the [`params()`](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#zend-mvc-controller-plugins-params)-plugin for now

Comment: This's really unexpected, but I can survive :)